# Use shell variable value in compile-time with "go build" command

Tags: go, compilation, g++

I'm building Golang project on gitlab CI and I'd like to pass `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` value to compiler. With `g++` it would be something like `g++ -DCI_COMMIT_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_TAG ...`. Is there anything simillar for `go build` command?

Answer (score 2):

main.go

```
package main

var YOUR_VARIABLE = ""

func main() {}
```

Shell command: `go build -ldflags "-X main.YOUR_VARIABLE=$your_variable" main.go`